# Haskell Identity Lens

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'm wondering if there is an identity lens in Haskell. A lens `identity` such that if I had a type `data MyType = MyType { _myField :: Int }`, then I can do `myType ^. identity . myField .~ 2` . There seemed to be one in `lens-1.1.1`, but I can't find one in `lens-4.19.2`.

Comment: I'm no Lens expert, but I don't really see the use of this - and if you do need it, given the definition of the `Lens` type, is it not just `id :: Lens s t s t`? Apologies if I've overlooked something obvious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of the nice things about `lens`-style lenses is that they're really just functions. So just as you can use the function composition operator `.` on lenses, you can also the identity function `id` as a lens, and it acts indeed as an identity-lens in the sense that it “focuses” on the entire data structure.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens

data MyType = MyType { _myField :: Int }
makeLenses ''MyType

main :: IO ()
main = print $ MyType 37 ^. id . myField
```

Comment: The implementation of `traverseOf` is also `id`.